# How to get the VB6 PRNG to generate a byte output from a specific seed, and how to replicate in C?

Tags: c, random, cryptography, vb6, reverse-engineering

Long time reader and lurker, first time poster.

I'm hoping to get some help regarding an old problem that has eluded me. I'm trying to figure out how the VB6 PRNG was used to generate a byte output from the two byte seed that the Randomize() function provided it. I'm trying to replicate the code in C and seed it with my own 2 bytes, something like 0x12FF.

I'm looking to create an 8 byte output, derived from 8x one byte outputs (as opposed to one 8-byte output) from the PRNG with a specific seed. The output would preferably be hexadecimal, as an example:
`0xFF 0x1A 0x2B 0x3C 0x4D 0x5E 0x6F 0x1A`

I understand that the VB6 PRNG has a massive flaw, my experiment is designed to demonstrate the flaw and why a PRNG such as that should not be used to avoid repeatable outputs.

The only documentation I can seem to find is how to generate an integer output, which isn't useful to me unless an integer output was somehow used to generate a byte output. I'm not familiar with the outputs and would appreciate any help I can get.

The integer output example I have is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
unsigned long       rndVal;

rndVal = 0x50000L; // default VB6 value of 327680, can I set this to a 2 byte value such as 0x12FF?
int i;
float rndFloat;

for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
    rndVal = (rndVal * 0x43fd43fdL + 0xc39ec3L) & 0xffffffL;
    rndFloat = (float)rndVal / (float)16777216.0;
    printf("Value is %.15f\n",rndFloat);
    }
return 0;
}
```

I can clearly see how to use my own seed by amending the rndVal value, how would one convert the output of this to a byte output the same wasy that VB6 did it, or does this require a complete rethink?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know how VB6 actually did it, but the simplest (and preferred, from my understanding of how RNGs work) approach to obtain a byte value would be to take the integer output (`rndVal` in the code example) modulo 256. Do you happen to have a running version of the VB6 PRNG with byte output so you can compare this option or any other possibilities with the output from the original VB6 code?

Comment: I don’t actually have an example, so I wouldn’t know how it was done I’m afraid. The mod 256 sounds like a good idea, I may try that as a first stop, thank you for the info!

Comment: Possibly someone on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ might also know this.

Comment: Side-question, why do you have to reverse-engineer or replicate the VB6 PRNG code in order to perform your demo?  If it makes any difference, you could create a VB6 DLL which you can call from C.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I had no idea crypto.stackexchange.com even existed, it's worth a shot. On the side question, I'm unsure of how VB6 did it, which is why I am unsure of how to proceed here. I'm also trying to write a simple shell based program, without the need for an external DLL.

Comment: If language were no issue then you could write a shell program (normally referred to as a command line program) in VB6, just FYI.

Comment: I believe we digress.. My question reads "How did the VB6 PRNG generate a byte output from a specific seed..." as I am unsure of how to do it in VB6. I also stated "I'm trying to figure out how the VB6 PRNG was used to generate a byte output from the two byte seed that the Randomize() function provided it." I have amended the title for clarity.

Comment: You need to provide some VB6 code showing what you mean by *how the VB6 PRNG was used to generate a byte output from the two byte seed that the Randomize() function provided it ...* There are no doubt numerous ways this can be done.